# Why do CUE sheet files have to have a blank line at the very end?

Tags: audio

I was trying to split a `.flac` file using its CUE sheet and the command `cuebreakpoints audiofile.cue | shnplit -o flac audiofile.flac`, but kept getting some error. Checking with other CUE sheets I have for other audio files, I realized they had a blank line at the very end, so I added said blank line to my `audiofile.cue` and suddenly everything worked. **So I wonder:** why do CUE sheet files need that additional blank line at the very end?